# instanced variable accessed in class method, Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class-method

This is the original codes when I am getting this error

ClassA.h

> +(ClassA*)methodA:(NSData*)data;
>
> ```
> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray    *arr; 
> @property (nonatomic, strong) RXMLElement     *rxmlRoot;
> ```
>
> @end

ClassA.m

> +(ClassA*)methodA:(NSData*)data {
>
> ```
> //NSLog(@"class is %@",[name class]);
> ClassA *ClassA   =   [[Stores alloc] init];
> arr        =   [NSMutableArray array];
> rxmlRoot   = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:data];
> ```
>
> }

I am reviewing my codes and now I have tow options to fix the code

**OptionA**

> ClassA.h
>
> ```
> +(ClassA*)methodA:(NSData*)data;
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray    *arr; 
> @property (nonatomic, strong) RXMLElement     *rxmlRoot; 
>
> @end
> ```
>
> ClassA.m
>
> ```
> +(ClassA*)methodA:(NSData*)data {
>
> //NSLog(@"class is %@",[name class]);
> ClassA *ClassA   =   [[Stores alloc] init];
> ClassA.arr        =   [NSMutableArray array];             <----- this has been modified
> ClassA.rxmlRoot   = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:data];<----- this has been modified
>
> }
> ```

**OptionB**

> ClassA.h
>
> ```
> +(ClassA*)methodA:(NSData*)data;
>
> @end
> ```
>
> ClassA.m
>
> ```
> static RXMLElement    *rxlRoot; <----- this has been added as class variable
> static NSMutableArray *arr;     <----- this has been added as class variable
>
> +(ClassA*)methodA:(NSData*)data {
>
> //NSLog(@"class is %@",[name class]);
> ClassA *ClassA   =   [[Stores alloc] init];
> arr        =   [NSMutableArray array];             
> rxmlRoot   = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:data];
> ```
>
> }

I try either optionA or optionB and the compiler does not complain anything and the codes work properly.

I see many posts following the optionB which create class variables.

**Question**: is optionA also a good way to follow when we are dealing with class method and class variable as well.

Please advice me on this issue and by the way if I have made mistakes somewhere, please correct me. Thanks

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. I ave just edited it again...I changed Stores to be ClassA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a designated initializer with a data parameter. Every class should have a designated initializer.

In your class method call the designated initializer passing in `data`.

Here is example code:

```
//ClassA.h
@class RXMLElement;

@interface ClassA : NSObject
+(ClassA*)methodA:(NSData*)data;
-(id)initWithData:(NSData*)data;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arr; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) RXMLElement    *rxmlRoot; 

@end

//ClassA.m
@implementation ClassA
@synthesize arr;
@synthesize rxmlRoot;

+(ClassA*)methodA:(NSData*)data {
    return [[ClassA alloc] initWithData:data];
}

-(id)initWithData:(NSData*)data {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        arr      = [NSMutableArray array];
        rxmlRoot = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:data];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

ARC is assumed in the example.

Comment: now the problem is in +(ClassA*), I cant access a var named rxmlRoot at all

Comment: Class methods can not access instance variables by design, there is no instance. Pass in anything you need. In general methods should not be made class methods unless they are "stand-alone". What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: what I do is +(ClassA*)methodA:(NSData*)data {
    ClassA *classA =  [[ClassA alloc] initWithData:data]; [arr addObject:nameOfAnObject]; return classA
}
. However, I cant access a var named rxmlRoot at all

Comment: Why are you trying to use that pattern and not the above example?

Comment: you are rite and I have just tried to format my codes ( based on your suggestion ). However, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS at whenever I tried to use ClassA.arr. I figured it out because we dont use **self**.arr or **self**. rxmlRoot when we were initializing these objects. However, I cant convince my self about the reason.... Do you have any explanation for it ?

Comment: Use ARC (Automatic reference Counting) it will make your life simpler, the code better and improve you social life. Without ARC you either need to retain `arr` and `rxmlRoot` or use `self.arr` and `self.rxmlRoot`, the later is discouraged by many in init methods and destructors. Best: use ARC and avoid the pain of manual retaining handling.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "class variable" in Objective-C.   When you declare a variable as `static` it is, effectively, a global variable that is limited to either the scope of the file it is compiled within or the scope of a method/function (or sub-expression).

Get rid of the `Class.` part of your calls to set the variables;  that'll work in the `.m` file for the Class only;  which is generally the pattern you would want (truly global variables are generally discouraged -- sometimes useful, though).